# 7-Zip-like software for OS X

Tags: osx, archiving

Is there any software that can do what 7-zip for Windows does. The functionality I need is adding, editing and deleting of files without expanding the archive. Also it has to work with Java archives like jars and wars.

In windows to edit a file in side the archive open the archive in 7zip and right click and click 'Edit' which will open the file in default application (in my case notepad) edit the file and save on closing the application (i.e notepad) 7zip will ask for confirmation to save the file.

The following are the screenshots of the steps.

**Opening an archive and Editing**

[image: Opening an archive]

**Editing In Notepad**

[image: Editing In Notepad]

**Saving the file**

[image: Saving the file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BetterZip](http://macitbetter.com/) is perfect for my needs.

BetterZip can browse, open a file and the file can be directly updated in the archive directly.

It's not free though.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) for [Mac](http://www.kekaosx.com/en/)?

You can find a list of items in the first link, and try installing from the source on Mac, or just go with the second link and install the provided software. It should do what you want.

Comment: These two software just compress and uncompress the files please check my updated question for more info.

Comment: Uh... I see now. I have something on my Mac for years, but can't remember what it is. Will check once I get home, although I'm not sure if it has this functionality. 
Do you want a GUI app only? CLI doesn't count?

Comment: GUI will be better, CLI also will do.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam since Mac is UNIX-based you already have all the standard CLI tools like tar, zip/unzip, bzip2, and most likely many others.

Comment: @AndréDaniel as I mentioned in my question I want to edit the files without unzip/uncompress the archive.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam maybe you don't know this but what 7 zip does under the hood is simply extracting the file to be edited into a temporary directory, then opening it in your text editor and finally putting back this temp file in the archive. So you can do the same with the UNIX CLI tools, look at their man pages for arguments to extract a single file instead of the whole archive.